# Url doesnt point to area index file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I want to make it possible for me to access my admin page when typing:

www.sitename.com/admin

I have decided to go with the area approuch. However it doesnt seem to work quite yet.

Ive created an Admin area and updated the route in the admin area registration. it looks like this:

```
        context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { area = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "skylearn.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { "skylearn.Controllers"}
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

however it seems that if i go to my url localhost:1337/admin the index file located in my HOME folder serviced by my HomeController wont load. These folders and controllers are also located inside the admin area.

any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "skylearn.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

You did not specify a default area or controller for your route.

Comment: that didnt change anything im afraid. thanks for the input though

Comment: I'm assuming skylearn in your namespace is the correct case and it is not SkyLearn?  Do you have any other routes that you have specified in your RegisterArea?  If so you should add the RegisterArea routine to your question as the order of routes can make a difference.

Comment: yes i have the default route registered as well. that route uses another namespace though. and yes skylearn is the namespace but it is written with a small s. im adding the register area now

Comment: If I understand you correctly in you RegisterArea method you have a single route named "Admin_default" and in RegisterRoutes you have the single default route.  I've just set up this scenario on my machine and it works fine, although I notice in the "Admin_default" route you have now added the default area I suggested but not the default controller.  Did you miss one?

Comment: problem solved. if you update your answer i will give u the thumbs up :D

Comment: I already specified the default area and default controller in my original answer :-)  Or did I miss something?